# What is a Notable Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>*In the spirit of the What is a [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion)/[Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463), a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) puzzles.*</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a ***Notable Word™***.
Use the examples below to find the rule.

| Notable Words™ | Not Notable Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| LIONESS | LION |
| FATAL | RUINOUS |
| NOTABLE | VIP |
| GRAB | HOOK |
| BREAKFAST | MORNIN' |
| GARFUNKEL | SIMON |
| FFAO | SHIRO |
| SHUFFLEBOARD | POOL |
| MANDIBLE | MOUTH |
| BARBED | THORNY |
| MICHIGAN | MISSISSIPPI |
| LETHARGIC | SNOOZY |
| DRAW | LIMN |
| CRESCENT | MOON |
| GYM | SPORT |

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Notable Words™,Not Notable Words™
LIONESS,LION
FATAL,RUINOUS
NOTABLE,VIP
GRAB,HOOK
BREAKFAST,MORNIN'
GARFUNKEL,SIMON
FFAO,SHIRO
SHUFFLEBOARD,POOL
MANDIBLE,MOUTH
BARBED,THORNY
MICHIGAN,MISSISSIPPI
LETHARGIC,SNOOZY
DRAW,LIMN
CRESCENT,MOON
GYM,SPORT
```

The puzzle satisfies the series' inbuilt assumption, that each word can be tested for whether it is a Notable Word™ without relying on the other words.
These are not the only examples of Notable Words™; many more exist.

**What is the special rule these words conform to?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A Notable word is one in which

> At least one of the letters in the word corresponds to a Musical Note, that is A-G.

Comment: And of course, now it's incredibly obvious. Nice.

Answer (score 3):

A Notable word is one which

> contains an A or an E.

I'm sure Sconibulus's answer is the right one, but mine works too, given the current crop of examples :D

Comment: That is indeed a problem with these sorts of puzzles - it all comes down to Occam's Razor, but needs enough examples to make the answer more enticing than any other. A few additional examples like GYM / SPORT would have helped, but the title makes it pretty clear what was intended as you note :)

Comment: "...technically correct: the best kind of correct" :)

Comment: I'm going to take Sp's idea and toss those in to invalidate this. Nothing against you just for completeness :)